# Shell script for directory creation

Tags: shell

I wrote a shell script to create a directory if it doesn't exist. I am able to create a new directory. But when I pass an existing directory name the `elif` statement is not being executed, instead `Created Directory` is printing. What am doing wrong?

```
if [[ ! -e /test/{a,b,c}/$dirname ]]; then
     mkdir "/test/{a,b,c}/$dirname" 
     echo "Created Directory"
elif  [[ ! -d /test/{a,b,c}/$dirname ]]; then
     echo "$dirname already exists"
fi
```

Here `test`, `a`, `b`, and `c` are directories.

Comment: **Why** do you need to know if they already exist? If you use `mkdir -p`, it'll create them only if they aren't already there, and you have no need to run a check.

Comment: If I pass existing directory name script should throw error too. This is what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: `mkdir -p "/test/{a,b,c}/$dirname" || printf "error: directory does not exist and couldn't create.\n"` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion isn't a globbing form performed on unquoted expansion. Consequently, you can't rely on `for dir in $dirs`: You need to either use an array to store brace expansion results, or iterate over such results directly.

If you want to create *any* directories only if *none* of the directories already exist:

```
# assign to an array
dirs=( /test/{a,b,c}/"$dirname" )

# iterate over contents and check, failing if any exists
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  [[ -d "$dir" ]] && { echo "$dir already exists" >&2; exit 1; }
done

# if we reach here, none of them exist, so create all directories with one mkdir call.
mkdir -- "${dirs[@]}" || exit # also, fail the script if mkdir fails
```

Alternately, if it's acceptable to take partial action:

```
for dir in /test/{a,b,c}/"$dirname"; do
  [[ -d "$dir" ]] && { echo "$dir already exists" >&2; exit 1; }
  mkdir -- "$dir"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also for creating a directory script is prompting to enter sudo password on terminal. Is there is a way to bypass this using expect programming?

Comment: Yes, but it's better to reconfigure sudo to not prompt for the password at all (with both configuration and validation making this permission as narrowly applicable as possible). For instance, you could allow only the specific user that needs to run this script to use passwordless sudo only to start the script -- or you could have another script allowed for passwordless sudo that does only the mkdir parts, with careful validation on arguments, environment variables (if your `sudoers` file allows them to be passed through) &c to make sure it can't be subverted by an attacker.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there is way to do this by using expert program?

Comment: @sudhirkumar, I presume you mean "expect"? Yes, it's possible, but it's also bad practice -- and because it's bad practice (requires passwords to be stored and made available in plaintext, which is inherently insecure), I decline to enable it.

Comment: Yes I meant expect. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a test on multiple dirs at once.

You need to loop over dirs :

```
dirs=( /test/{a,b,c}/"$dirname" )
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
         mkdir "$dir" 
         echo "Created Directory"
    else
         echo >&2 "$dir already exists"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I need to verify whether directory is existing or not.

Comment: Still facing same issue.

Comment: Been through the edited one. Still facing same issue

Comment: I am passing dirname as variable

Comment: Wouldn't it be more proper to use an array? `dirs=( /test/{a,b,c}/"$dirname" ); for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do ...` -- btw, the code in the answer is still using `$dirname` rather than `$dir` in at least one place.

Comment: Also, right now, we echo "Created Directory" even if `mkdir` failed. Suggest `mkdir "$dirname" && echo "Created Directory" >&2` (it's human-targeted narrative/logging, so stderr is the right place).

Comment: ...and we have a needless bashism by putting the `>&2` in the middle of the latter `echo` rather than at the beginning or end, as POSIX mandates to work.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I am able to create using array. Thanks

Comment: @sudhirkumar, glad that works. Since that particular suggestion hasn't been adopted by Gilles, I'll add my own answer.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, ...btw, if you want a demonstration that this code is innately broken without that fix: `glob={a,b,c}; for item in $glob; do echo "$item"; done`

Comment: Looks good -- only thing that still jumps out at me is always saying "Created Directory" if we *tried* to run `mkdir`, whether or not it succeeded.